# Arithmetic operation Rule in C language

Tags: c, math

**I am new to C language :)**

Although the code runs perfectly, I cannot understand how it is operating. I mean let's take (k = i / j * j) as an example, according to mathematic rules the answer should be k = 2 but the program output is 0. can anyone help me out with what rule C language is applying to it?

```
int   i = 2, j=3, k,l;
float   a, b;
k = i / j * j;
l = j / i * i;
a = i / j * j;
b = j / i * i;
printf( "%d %d %f %f", k, l, a, b );
```

Comment: Multiplication and division have the same precedence in C, unlike in mathematics, and bind left-to-right. Considering `k = i / j * j;` — since `j > i`, `i / j` is zero, and `0 * j` is also zero. Note that the arithmetic for `a` and `b` is done as integer arithmetic; only the (integer) result is converted to a floating point value.  You should end your print format with a newline.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "*unlike in mathematics*" - that's news to me...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: I am under the illusion that mathematicians treat `a ÷ b•c` as `a / (b * c)` rather than `(a / b) * c`, whereas C treats it as `(a / b) * c` rather than `a / (b * c)`.

Comment: Computers 101: 'redundant brackets are not a sin', 'intermediate, temporary variables are not a sin':)

Answer (score 2):

According to the operator precedence of the C language, the corresponding operation is performed as follows.

[image]

```
k = i / j * j;
  = (i / j) * j;
  = (2 / 3) * 3
  = 0 * 3
  = 0
```

Note: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

(As you probably know, division between Integers cannot represent a decimal point as an operation.)